# Disabled sorting option enables on page refresh

Tags: discussion, bug, new-nav, sorting

The sorting options *ending* and *bounty size* which appear disabled on switching between tags enables on refresh:

**Before Refresh**
[image]

**After Refresh**
[image]

Though clicking on those disable it again.

<s>Are these sorting options only for a specific tag? I am curious to know in which scenario are these sorting options enabled?</s>

**EDIT** Figured out it is only for bounties tab.